# AIX binaries - size & symbols

Tags: unix, aix

There are a few differences noticed in symbols between two binaries built using same sources on two AIX systems. One example for 'main':

---

```
xxxx1: .main                T  4294975624
```

---

```
xxxx2: .main                T  4294969472         516
xxxx2: main:F-1             -           0
```

---

Why the difference in sizes?

'T' is Global text symbol as per man page. What is 'F'?

Also, the sizes of two binaries vary significantly: 3924048 vs. 17701460. Why?

AIX versions, compiler versions, makefiles (same CFLAGS) are identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly sure the F-1 is a function returning int.  It is a "stab" string which is output when the compiler given the -g option.  That would also be the reason for the size differences.

Can you try doing "size " and "size ".  size also has an option to make it more verbose.  You can also do "file " etc and it will tell you if it is stripped or not.

Between the -g and the strip flag at link time, I think that will account for the differences you are seeing.

HTH